# Angular not detect push to list despite of changing reference

Tags: angular, reference

I have following scenario :

```
@Injectable()
export class AppserviceService {

  constructor() { }

  personList: Person[] = [];

  mySubject = new Subject<Person>();
  myAction = this.mySubject.asObservable().pipe(
    tap((person) => {
      // this.personList.push(person)
      // console.log(this.personList)
      this.personList.push(Object.assign({}, person)); //change reference
    })
  ).subscribe();

}
```

```
export class AppComponent{
  form: FormGroup;
  personsList: Person[];
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private service: AppserviceService){}

  addPerson(){
    const persona = <Person>{
      Name : 'ALEX',
      Age : 43,
    }
    this.service.mySubject.next(persona)
  }
  
}
```

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() listaPerson : Person[];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes){
      console.log(changes) //CHANGES ARE NO DETECT
    }
  }
```

In child I have ngOnChange method which not works despite of fact that I change reference in service ... why it's not detect?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-template-vwpj2b?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

So, I checked out your project, and it seems the `personsList` in the `app.component.ts` wasn't the same reference as the one in the `appservice.service.ts`.

To alleviate that, all you need to do is the following in the `AppComponent`.

```
personsList: Person[] = this.service.personList;
```

This will provide the same reference, and everytime you click on "CHECK PERSONS" you will have a new item in the array, visible in the console.